# TOF camera calibration - distance to chessboard

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, camera-calibration

For my application, I need to calibrate my **TOF**-camera (kinect v2).

I have done this with matlab camera calibration. After my calibration, I recognized that right-angled planes are oblique.
For example here a result of two "right-angled" planes:

[image: Wrong Calibration]

I think this result is so oblique cause of the wrong parameters from calibration. Therefore I want to improve my calibration process of the kinect.

**So I have three major questions:**

1. Is the distance between TOF-camera and chessboard important for the calibration result? For my application, I need a quite high accurancy in the interval 2.5m - 3m (Z-distance between camera and object). So I choose this intervall to get the best result for this area, expecialy because it is a TOF-camera.  Or should I take a quite short distance (1-1.5m) to get a good chessboard with a high resolution?
2. What kind of images (viewpoint: rotated,obiquely / images in the middle or corner) are important to get a good result for the tangential distortion ( I think this parameter turns totataly wrong)? Any tipps to improve here my results?
3. I fixed my chessboard on a flat wall and fixed my camera on a tripod. For different calibration images I move my tripod. Would this procedure be also ok? Or do I have to move the chessboard pattern to get better results?

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ?